# How to run Python Scripts on Mac Terminal using Docker with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, macos, docker, machine-learning, tensorflow

I just got a Mac and shifted from Windows and installed Tensorflow using Docker and everything is working fine, but I want to run a python script that I have from before. Is there any way to run a python script in docker on a Mac, using the terminal?

Comment: you need to add more info in order to give a better response. The assumption is that you build a docker image with Tensorflow, in that case; How are you building your docker image? is the python script in some repository or on your local machine? and what python version was the script built on (2.x/3.x)?

Comment: I am using the command `docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow`, and the script is on my local machine, and am using Python 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below should do...

Create a Dockerfile with the below content:

```
FROM gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest
COPY script.py /usr/bin/
CMD ["python", "/usr/bin/script.py"]
```

build the image:

```
$ docker build -t mytensorflow .
```

run it:

```
$ docker run -it --rm mytensorflow
```

if you want to keep the container going after the script is run don't --rm it...

Comment: `FROM gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest` returns `FROM: can't read /var/mail/gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest`

Answer (score 2):

More information would be very helpful, but perhaps this is useful for you.

It depends on a lot of different factors, but assuming a couple of things:

**The docker containing Tensorflow has a name like 'tensorflow' already contains the python script:** 
you can use: 
docker run tensorflow 'python '

**If the script is not yet present, you can either use build a docker based on that image using a docker file, something along the lines of:**

```
FROM tensorflow:latest
ADD /some/local/path.py /the/path/on/my/docker
```

Or you can create/run the docker interactively by doing something along the lines of:

Docker run -ti tensorflow /bin/bash
Which will start an instance of the tensorflow container and start /bin/bash on it. 
You now have an interactive shell so can place the python script any way you want and start it.

Comment: Once I enter `docker run -it tensorflow/tensorflow /bin/bash`, how do I enter the python script that I want to run?

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you have a script `my_script.py` located at `/Users/awesome_user/python_scripts/` on your mac

By default the tensorFlow image bash will locate you at /notebooks.

Run this command in your terminal:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /Users/awesome_user/python_scripts/:/notebooks gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow bash
```

This will map your local mac folder `/Users/awesome_user/python_scripts/` to the docker's local folder `/notebooks`

then just run from the bash `python my_script.py`. Also running `ls` should reveal your folder content

Comment: Obviously, feel free to replace `/notebooks` with whatever local docker folder :)